# Grab specific parts of a string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to grab a specific part of a string which has a start charecter and an end charecter.

For example;

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum |example xyz|dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit |example|. Vivamus at posuere magna. Suspendisse rutrum rhoncus leo
vitae vehicula. Nunc nec dapibus nisi. Donec facilisis mauris sapien, eget
blandit enim |example xyz| dignissim auctor.|example| Nullam a porta orci.
Donec pharetra urna odio, ut pellentesque est eleifend vel. Nulla tincidunt
tellus sed dui fermentum viverra. Vivamus sit amet semper mi."
```

I want grab parts all `|example xyz| .. blabla.. |example|`.

How can I do this ?
Thank you..

Comment: What have you tried, is the expected result an array of the matches or the first match?

Comment: You could explode on `|` and discard the odd keys in the result (as these would always contain `example` or `example xyz`..

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringcutout($string,$start,$stop)
{
 $ret='';
 if (strstr($string,$start))
 {
  $p=strpos($string,$start);
  $b=substr($string,$p+strlen($start));
  if (strstr($b,$stop))
  {
   $p=strpos($b,$stop);
   $b=substr($b,0,$p);
   $ret=$b;
  }
 }
 return $ret;
}
```

I'm using this. I know it's not pretty, but working ...

Comment: please note, this function looks for the first occurence of the string only.

Comment: no I thing it's good but I want to get an array which include the whole parts of "|example xyz| .. blabla.. |example|". in your function my result return an empty string.

Comment: $start='|example xyz|';
$stop='|example|';

$ret=stringcutout($str,$start,$stop);
print($ret);

this  returns for me: dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for that `\|([\w\s]+)\|` to get any words between `|`

**UPDATE**

To include `|example xyz|` and `|example|` use this regex:

```
(\|example xyz\|[\w\s]\|example\|)
```

Comment: I think he wants the parts "outside" of the pipes.

Comment: actually I want the whole parts. The whole "|example xyz| .. blabla.. |example|"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed string that you're looking to find you could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
preg_match_all('/\|example xyz\|[\w\s\,\.]+\|example\|/', $str, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 0)
{
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
    {
        echo $match;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always returns empty array.

Comment: Well then, could you show me how you used preg_match?

Comment: Check my new edit, should give you "|example xyz| text |example|" in $matches

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need a different function ...
You can get multiple contents including anything starts with |example with this function:

```
$return=array(); 
$ex=explode('|example',$str);
if (sizeof($ex)>0) {unset($ex[0]); foreach ($ex as $s) {$x=strpos($s,'|'); $return[]=substr($s,$x+1);}}
```

if you don't want the extra last result (which is not "terminated" by |example), you can unset it ...